# VBscript variable is undefined error

Tags: vbscript

Here is my vbscript - not got too far with this. The 2 lines I've lifted from Microsoft documentation don't work. The file is saved as a vbs file. I'm doubleclicking to run. Windows XP is the OS.

```
option explicit

Dim Rs1
Set Rs1 = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
```

I get a runtime error saying error: variable is undefined: 'Server'. Bit puzzled by this as the code is sooooo basic.

Any ideas anyone? thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Server.CreateObject` is for *ASP Pages*, for "desktop" VBScript use:

```
option explicit

Dim Rs1
Set Rs1 = CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
```

Comment: `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` and `CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")` work with Classic ASP: `<%@language="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" LCID=1033%>`. I guess it depends on how IIS is set up and how your files and folders security is set.